# Google analytics event lag

Tags: javascript, web, google-analytics, report, google-analytics-api

I have 2 questions concerning Google Analytics:

1). I am sending an event like:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'myCategory', 'myAction', 'myLabel + (generated value)');
```

This event is shown in the Real-Time->Events tab as soon as they are sent, but in my custom Report containing:

```
Dimensions: 'Event Category', 'Event Action'
Metrics: 'Total Events'
Filters: Include 'Event Category' exact 'myCategory'
```

nothing is shown. Is there some lag between real-time and reporting? (I am waiting for 30 minutes and nothing is shown in the report).

2). For the above Custom report, how do I include 'Event Label'? To print that value as well for each event in when I export to PDF.

Regards,
Tamash

Answer (score 0):

based on your main problem, showing event category, action, & label in a one report. Unfortunately, Google analytics only support up to two dimensions at a time. Hence, this report you have created (Flat table type) can only indicate two dimensions at a time.

About the report filter, to me you have filtered data based on the Event Category . Try to include Unique Events and Total Events both as metrics.

**My Suggestion :**

Dimensions: 'Event Action', 'Event Label'

Metrics: 'Unique Events', 'Total Events'

Filters: Include 'Event Category' exact 'myCategory'

If this method is not convening , use “Explorer” type  and make it to drill down by the Event Category and in the second stage use “secondary dimension “ to get the output.